# How to get the current path without last folder in a script?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I want to run a script that saves the current path into a variable, excluding the folder itself where the script runs in. Example:

`/tmp/test/test2/test3/test.sh`

```
path=$PWD
echo $path
```

Gives `/tmp/test/test2/test3`. 
But I want to exclude the folder where the sh script is in.

So my desired output would be:
`/tmp/test/test2`

Comment: Are you talking about the current (working) directory, where the script is *running,* or the directory where the script is *stored?*

Comment: I would use `realpath ..` (the question is tagged `ubuntu`, so a linux-only solution is OK)

Answer (score 8):

You may use

```
dir=${PWD%/*}    # or:  dir=$( dirname "$PWD" )
```

or

```
dir="$PWD/.."
```

or

```
dir=".."
```

In the first case, the `PWD` variable, which contains the current working directory, is used to get the path of the directory one level up by removing the last `/` and everything after it.

In the second case, the `PWD` variable is used to simply create a path for the directory above using `..`.

In the third case, we simply refer to the directory above using a relative path from the current directory.

Which alternative you use is dependent on what you are going to use the path for.

Examples:

```
$ echo $PWD
/tmp/shell-sh.jAtMYgn0
```

```
$ dir=${PWD%/*}
$ echo "$dir"
/tmp
```

```
$ dir="$PWD/.."
$ echo "$dir"
/tmp/shell-sh.jAtMYgn0/..
```

```
$ dir=".."
$ echo "$dir"
..
```

Comment: Note that if `$PWD` is `/`, `${PWD%/*}` becomes the empty  string while `dirname /` outputs `/`. In any case, `/` would probably have to be handled specially.

Comment: Note that if `$PWD` is `/tmp` and `/tmp` is a symlink to `/var/tmp`, `$PWD/..` refers to `/var`, not `/` (except for `cd` in POSIX-like shells, when not passed the `-P` option).

Answer (score 4):

try the following code,

```
dirname "$(pwd)"
```

- dirname - strip suffix from file/dir path

Comment: leave the variable empty. I'm on `ubuntu` if that matters.. By the ways this works inside a terminal, but not in a script assigning it to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh`:

```
dir=$PWD:h
```

Like `dirname`, That removes one directory component off the end of `$PWD`. When  `$PWD` is `/`, `$dir` becomes `/` like with `dirname`.

One advantage over

```
dir=$(dirname -- "$PWD")
```

is that it still works if the dirname of `$PWD` ends in newline characters.

Note that it is not necessarily the parent of the current directory. For instance, when `$PWD` is `/tmp` and `/tmp` happens to be a symlink to `/var/tmp`, the parent directory of the current directory would be `/var`, not `/`. To get the parent directory, you could do:

```
dir=$PWD/..
dir=$dir:P
```

or:

```
dir=$PWD:P:h
```

(the `:P` modifier makes `$dir` a canonical path (resolves all symlink, `.`, and `..` components like GNU `readlink -f`)).

Or POSIXly:

```
dir=$(cd -P .. && pwd -P)
```

In any case, note that `$PWD` within a script has nothing to do with the path of the script. If you want the parent directory of the directory containing the script, that would be `$0:P:h:h` in `zsh`.

Answer (score -1):

Finally it was as simple as: `current=$(dirname "$(pwd)")`

Answer (score -1):

Current working directory ie: /home/dev/other

```
dir=$PWD
```

Parent directory

```
parentdir="$(dirname "$dir")"`
```

Comment: This answer has been given multiple times already (but without the unnecessary step of copying one variable to another).

Comment: @G-Man, technically it hadn't until I added my answer (shortly after Piyush's) as the other answers either use `${PWD%/*}` or `dirname "$(pwd)"`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Well, [Kusalananda’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/462701/80216#462705) says ``dir=$( dirname "$PWD" )`` in a comment, indicating that it is equivalent to his primary answer of ``dir=${PWD%/*}`` (although it isn’t).  Also, lgeorget deleted [their answer (10K only)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/462701/80216#462703) of ``dirname $PWD``, possibly because it was considered to be equivalent to [msp9011’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/462701/80216#462702) of ``dirname "$(pwd)"``. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (I hope you aren’t giving Piyush Sharma ‘credit’ for having a new and unique answer just because they copied ``$PWD`` into another variable before passing it to ``dirname``.)